# Installing chrome OS on an iMac

Tags: google-chrome-os

http://zzsethzz.blogspot.de/2013/02/install-chromium-upgrade-it-to-chrome.html

According this tutorial, I should remove all HDDs I do not want to install chromium OS to during install. I wanted to try this guide on my imac using an external SSD for chromeos. Obviously, removing the HDD isn't an option. Will the chromiumOS installer format my mac drive too, if I don't remove it?﻿

Answer (score 0):

AS the writer of that tutorial I can hopefully help you. When you install Chromium OS to begin with you can specify where to install to if you know your unix commands well enough. and then from there you can update to Chrome OS once you have your external working for you.

To find out what your hard drive is when connected, open a terminal (you may need to use a developer terminal) and use the command "fdisk -l" This will list your hard drives. for example /dev/sda1  etc...

Your install command would be "Install /Dev/sda1" but replace the dev part with whatever your hard drive was listed as. If you need further help email me at admin@xiaorishu.co.uk